# Can't move links on Desktop

Tags: gui

I drag-dropped some links from the Chrome Browser onto the Desktop. But now when I try to move them they create a file rather than being moved.

**1**
[image]

**2**
[image]

**3**
[image]

Could someone tell me how to fix this. *(And maybe why it is happening)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug ([bugzilla.gnome.org](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720390), [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1278437). As far as I know there is no way to fix this (without fixing it in the Nautilus source code).

Comment: I am running 14.10. Would reverting back to 14.04 fix this?

Comment: No, Nautilus in 14.04 has the same bug. As far as I remember it's working in 12.04.

Comment: So.. EVERYONE has this bug right now?

Comment: Yes, everybody who is using Nautilus 3.10. I don't know if it's fixed in more recent versions of Nautilus.

Comment: Thank you.. I am using version 3.10.1.
So would you suggest that I switch to a different file manager?

Comment: You could try to use Nemo instead of Nautilus.

Comment: Alright thank you. I think I will go and play with Mint for a while. I wanted to do that for a long time anyways. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 5):

The current 16.01 LTS ships with gnome `3.14.4`, and this bug is fixed in `3.15.4` onwards.

**Backup and proceed with caution with the following...**

You can update your version of nautilus, as shown [in this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/783287/109484):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After a reboot, this worked for me, but I ended up with huge icons. The previous preferences icon zoom menu option disappeared, but then I found [this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689097/is-there-some-way-to-decrease-folders-icons-size-in-nautilus-3-18/689839#689839), which worked for me:

- open a file browser
- click the icon view button
- move the slider to the left

[image]

> Note: Screen-shot credit to @Manje Brinkhuis

Answer (score 3):

A handy workaround I discovered:

R click and choose cut on the link icon you want to move.  Then R click and choose paste on the desktop location to which you want to move it.  When a popup comes up and says "Do you want to replace?", say yes!