# Small icons after Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, icons

Some desktop icons (not all icons) got super small after I upgraded to 16.04. I tried right-clicking on an icon and selecting the 'Resize Icon...' option but this doesn't work, all this does is move the icon around. The resize option works for some icons but not all. What else can I try that will increase the icon size?

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83099/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size) :

> Also, maybe you could try "gconf-editor." In it, go to apps>nautilus>icon_view. There's a setting for icon size there. Maybe that's what you need

and

> I did it. I go to "Nautilus/Preferences/My Icon View Default", it zooms 400%. Changing it to 100% solved the problem. Thanks for the tips nautilus > icon_view

Comment: I searched for icon size in 'apps>nautilus>icon_view' but this setting does not exist. Also, 'Nautilus/Preferences/My Icon View Default' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

open Nautilus, any folder, look to the top right for the button to change from the icon view from list/detail, etc, there is a slider bar in that dropdown menu, for me it only had three positions but it did adjust the size of all my icons.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds kind of weird, but I managed to change the size of the icons by open a folder (any folder) with files inside (any type of files) and keep pressing Ctrl + Mouse Scroll, this change the size for all files inside and outside the folder.

Sometimes best solutions are the easiest.

PSDT: Also you could refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/689839/497512), which in esence is the same solution.

Comment: Yep also CTR +  + :D