# How to reduce all the folder and file icon size?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, xubuntu, directory, resize

After updating to latest version 16.04, automatically all the folder and file icon sizes have increased. Even my search bar size has increased.

How to resolve this ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/689097/is-there-some-way-to-decrease-folders-icons-size-in-nautilus-3-18

Comment: Hold CTRL and scroll the center mouse wheel to change the zoom size.

Comment: not working bro...

Comment: Downloaded unity tweak tool ,it worked thanx for he link @terrance

Comment: Mattias gave you the link.  I was just suggesting the CTRL+Mouse wheel for adjusting zoom.