# Is it possible to set the default icon size smaller than the lowest nautilus value

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, icons

I am trying to set the default desktop icon size to a really small value, because the `small` option in `org->gnome->nautilus->icon-view` (dconf editor) is still too large for my taste.

Is is possible to set that value to an even smaller one somehow? Maybe there's a way to set the smallest icon size in pixels somewhere? I'm new to Ubuntu and I haven't found anything useful on the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/930512/).