# Icons too big after update Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: icons, ubuntu-gnome

I applied some pending updates this morning, and after restarting all the icons (desktop and file explorer) were huge:
[image: icons]

I tried changing the zoom settings in the file explorer to small, but that only makes them a bit smaller (still huge), I also tried messing with the dconf Editor, but that does nothing.

I also tried

```
DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

unity --reset-icons

setsid unity
```

but no luck, still the same.

How can I set everything back to normal?

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME Metacity desktop and arc dark theme

Comment: I already tried that (except the recompile) and it doesn't work

Comment: Which one did you try? Doesn't <ctrl>+<-> reduce icon size?

Comment: it does but it's already in the smallest setting and it's really big

Comment: Ahh... then unfortunately you'll have to recompile nautilus as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/930512/480481), probably no other option.

Comment: I get an error when doing configure: No package 'gail-3.0' found  I tried apt-get install libgail-common  and gail-3.0 but that doesn't seem to be the right package, do you have any idea how to install gail?

Answer (score 0):

I used the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930512/819589) to downgrade nautilus to 3.14, and I'm never ever updating anything again, because everytime I do it something in Ubuntu breaks (last time was grub).