# How do I upgrade Gnome Files (nautilus) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-gnome, 16.04

I was using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and had upgrade gnome shell via ppa to 3.18. Yesterday I updated my distro to 16.04 and was surprised to find files is now version 3.14!

How can I get the latest version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the gnome3 repository to your system and upgrade.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I had to first remove the old ppa:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

then update the dist

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and only then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```