# Nautilus not launching on Wayland

Tags: gnome, nautilus, wayland

I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I have tried with Wayland session and it is soo cool. I love it because on normal session, I have some screen tearing issue which is not present at all in Wayland. Also the animations are far smoother than normal gnome session.

But there is a trouble I'm facing. On my normal gnome session, I can open nautilus without any problem. But on Wayland session, nautilus doesn't open up. It shows the icon at the top bar and then go away.

This is what I get while tried to open nautilus with terminal:

```
shoumma@dell-3442:~/Downloads$ nautilus .
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know Wayland is still in progress on Ubuntu, but is there any way I can overcome this issue? I have googled for solution but can't find anything about it. I really love the Wayland technology. Please let me know if there is any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!!! Thanks to this answer: [How do I upgrade Gnome Files (nautilus) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760309/how-do-i-upgrade-gnome-files-nautilus-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04)

The problem was, nautilus wasn't updated to 3.18 in Ubuntu Gnome. I have updated it with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And yes, it works!!!